# Expand macro inside string literal

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, macros, c-preprocessor

What I'm trying to do is to `#define` a macro:

```
#define a(2)
```

and later use it inside a string literal: `string = "a";`.

I want that string to be interpreted not as string but to get the value of `a`, i.e. 2. I didn't succeed, can anybody help?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
#define STRINGIFY2(X) #X
#define STRINGIFY(X) STRINGIFY2(X)
#define A 2
```

Then `STRINGIFY(A)` will give you `"2"`. You can concatenate it with other string literals by putting them side by side.

`"I have the number " STRINGIFY(A) "."` gives you `"I have the number 2."`.

Comment: Now add the crucial element that adjacent string literals are concatenated and this is an answer.

Comment: If you don't want to rely on the concatenation feature, you may try: `STRINGIFY(I have the number A)` (I'm not sure about the dot at the end).

Comment: Note the extra indirection with the wrapped expansions, which is required.

Comment: I'm using `#include "filename_" STRINGIFY(VERSION) ".hpp"` and I'm getting two errors: `fatal error: filename_: No such file or directory` and `warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive` (pointing at the STRINGIFY)

Answer (score 8):

No, you cannot do macro expansion INSIDE string literals (i.e. having the preprocessor to look inside literals for macros to expand).

You can have a macro expansion to produce a string literal using the stringify operator (`#`). But that's a different thing.