# Does this still declare an alias for a type of pointer function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, declaration, calling-convention

I am using some standard libraries to develop a general interface for some devices.
In some part of code I have

```
//header.h

#ifndef _M_X64
#  define GC_CALLTYPE __stdcall
#else
#  define GC_CALLTYPE /* default */  //this is my case
#endif

...


typedef int32_t GC_ERROR;

...


/* typedefs for dynamic loading */

#define GC_API_P(function) typedef GC_ERROR( GC_CALLTYPE *function )
GC_API_P(PTLOpen)( TL_HANDLE *phTL );
```

and in my source files I have

```
//source1.cpp

TLOpen(&hTl)

//source2.cpp

#define FUNCTION_POINTER(function, ptype, hModule) \
   ((function) = reinterpret_cast<ptype>(GetProcAddress((hModule), #function)))  // What is this #?
GC::PTLOpen TLOpen = 0;
FUNCTION_POINTER(TLOpen, GC::PTLOpen, hModule);
```

I want to find out:

1. What is the `TLopen()` declaration? I replaced macros and got this:

`typedef int32_t( GC_CALLTYPE *PTLOpen  )( TL_HANDLE *phTL );`

But I have learned function pointers differently and I expected something like this:

`typedef int32_t( *PTLOpen  )( TL_HANDLE *phTL );`

Is the above declaration still a function pointer one? What about `GC_CALLTYPE`?

2. What is that `#` sign before `function` in defining `FUNCTION_POINTER` macro?
3. Where is the body of `TLopen()` function? I have some `.lib` and `.dll` files to be included. May the body exist in those files in compiled form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `GC_CALLTYPE` is in a place where a [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) specifier can be (like `__stdcall`). *Can* be because don't forget that very easily `GC_CALLTYPE` can also expand to an empty string. A quick search gave a question where this syntax is discussed here in SO: [How to declare an __stdcall function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298394/how-to-declare-an-stdcall-function-pointer)
2. This is called stringification: for example `#function` will expand to `"xyz"` if the corresponding macro argument was `xyz`. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631922/expand-macro-inside-string-literal).
3. Yes, it can, in either actually. Your API will tell you how to do the compilation so that the program can find the function. This is the whole purpose of having libraries and a [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)).

Comment: So that is still a function pointer declaration. Please notice that in my case `_M_X64` is defined and `#define GC_CALLTYPE`, so `GC_CALLTYPE` is nothing but a macro! How does it work?

Comment: I am also curious to know if there is a way to detect that in which `.lib` file the body of a particular function exists. In other words, is there a way to find that, for example,  `func1` is defined in `.lib3` or `func3` in `.lib2`?

Comment: @GmtK Sorry, I overlooked the "this is my case". It's even easier then: after the preprocessor pass the compiler will only see `typedef int32_t( *PTLOpen  )( TL_HANDLE *phTL );`. The expansion `/* default */` is as good as white space, and actually gets replaced by that.

Comment: @GmtK Unfortunately I don't know Windows tools. In Linux you have several ways of browsing through the symbols of a static or a dynamic library so there will be some as well. But that's something for another question.