# Lintering warning whereas compilation is ok

Tags: makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have some variables defined in makefile.init:

```
MY_VARIABLE = some_value
```

In the preprocessor settings I have this -D switch:

```
-DUSE_MY_VAR=\"$(MY_VARIABLE)\"
```

And in a source file, I have this:

```
static const char* my_val = USE_MY_VAR;
```

So this my_val will get the value set in the makefile.init file.

It compiles just fine, but the indexer complains with a warning "Bad character sequence encountered: \". Is there a way to make it understand it or maybe make it ignore this specific variable?

Answer (score 2):

Ok finally found something that make both compiler and indexer happy:

my -D switch becomes (removed the escaped quotes):

```
-DUSE_MY_VAR=$(MY_VARIABLE)
```

and in the source code (thanks to [Expand macro inside string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631922/expand-macro-inside-string-literal)):

```
#define STRINGIFY2(X) #X
#define STRINGIFY(X) STRINGIFY2(X)

static const char* my_val = STRINGIFY(USE_MY_VAR);
```